# Why is the header pushed down when I add button navigation?

Tags: html, css

The #header was on the top of the browser with no space. 
But when I added this #buttons div, it pushed down the header creating about half inch of blank space on the top? How can I take out the space on top?

CSS

```
#body { margin: 0;}
#container {width:776px; height: 614;}
#content {margin-left: 40px; margin-top: -24px; width: 601px; height: 614;}
#buttons {margin-top: 70px;}
#header {position:absolute; margin-top: 0; height: 57px; width: 776px; background: url(images/headerbg.jpg) no-repeat;
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="navbar"> </div>
<div id="content"> 
     <div id="buttons"> <img src="images/btn_intro.gif" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused because it's inheriting the float vlaue from the parent element.

You can update your code by override the inherited styling by using the following code:

```
#buttons {
    float: left;
}
```

Likewise you can set the ID to an `inline-block` to get a similar effect:

```
#buttons {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
#buttons {float:inherit;}
```

inherit means use the same value as the same property his parent has.

You can change it to

```
#buttons {float:left;}
```

If doesn't work

```
#buttons {display: inline-block;}
```